# Firemonkey and dockable forms

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is it possible to have dockable forms in FireMonkey, as I have inspected the forms properties, and there is no such property to do that.
Is there any workaround to accomplish that?

Comment: It is technically doable, but I don't think it exists intrinsically like it did in the VCL forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in, as far as I know but it shouldn't be too difficult to add in yourself. Just bear in mind that any form can parent any control on another form:

On the child form, add any controls inside a container (e.g. a TLayout).
Create the child form.
Set the Parent property of the TLayout (etc.) to the parent form (or, more probably a container on the parent form so you can set the child TLayout's alignment to alClient).

If you want to show the placement during a drag operation, experiment with the various effec ts included.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike VCL, the Firemonkey does not have a built-in dockable interface for creating dock forms. But there is a commercial component for creating a complete dockable interface in FMX. The component implements dockable forms only. So far, the docked document panels are not supported (like the visual studio IDE does) and no docked toolbars. But in general, they have all the necessary functionality, including auto-hide panels and the ability to be saved/restored in/from XML.

https://www.devmachines.com/firedocking-overview.html